# Is the usage of 'of course' correct in this sentence?

Tags: editing

Is the usage of **of course** correct in this sentence? Is it the right context?

> After 60 blissful years, even today, all the school memories are
>   still vivid and heartwarming. **Of course**, happy memories never wear
>   out.

Answer (score 2):

Looks good to me. It makes sense, it's placed correctly in the sentence, it's spelled and capitalized accurately.

Not sure if this something you're writing or just curious about, but if you're editing your own writing, I would move **even today** in front of **after 60 blissful years** and make one other minor change.

Like so:

> ***Even today, after 60 blissful years, all those school memories are still vivid and heartwarming. Of course, happy memories never wear
>   out.***

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it was helpful.